# Composer update throws error 'Allowed memory size of XXXXXX bytes exhausted'

Tags: laravel, composer-php

On composer update commond throws error 'Allowed memory size of XXXXXX bytes exhausted'.
Memory limit is unlimited in php.ini file
**memory_limit = -1**

Is there another way to fix this..

Comment: what is your php version and composer version? please post the code of your composer.json file!

Comment: php version is 5.5.9

Comment: If you can try update your PHP version. 7.x has many performance improvements. Failing that you will probably need a machine with more RAM.

Comment: But when I tried composer install command then its working perfect..

Answer (score -2):

`composer update` updates your dependency tree to `composer.lock` and needs a lot of RAM (just had the same problem that morning when 1.5 GB were not enough....), `composer install` just uses the existing `composer.lock` to install the packages that are listed.

To get the problem better: why does the error message say `Allowed memory size of XXXXXX bytes exhausted` - that does not look like a PHP error...